# How to store a table in Java and retrieve data from it?

Tags: java

The first column will have serial number, the second, third, and fourth will have x-coordinate, y-coordinate and velocity. I might have to retrieve any of the fields, given the serial number. Say I want to get the y-coordinate of serial number 7, or the velocity of serial number 10. One way is to have an inner class with x,y and velocity and map serial numbers to objects of the inner class. But it makes things look complicated and retrieving a particular field value seems complex. Any better solution?

Comment: Just an addition: The serial numbers will be unique.

Comment: In my program itself. The program will use it.

Comment: Why not create an Object and store it there? Or an Multi-dimensional array?

Answer (score 1):

Create a key object which implements hashCode() and equals() correctly.  It appears that your serial numbers might be directly usable.

Create a data object with all fields you will need to store, and a getX() and setX() for each field x.

Create a `Map<KeyObject,DataObject>` and use that with your (key, data) pairs.

Be very careful to remove outdated objects or you will have a memory leak.

Comment: could you please elaborate or give a link about the last point u mentioned? "Be very careful to remove outdated objects or you will have a memory leak." Don't have much about what it means. thank you.

Comment: If you keep stuffing in objects in your Map, they will stay around until the map is garbage collected.  Hence if there are pairs that you know you will never use again, you need to remove them manually from the map instead of relying on the garbage collector.

Comment: ok. how to explicitly delete the object I don't need?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1):

What about using Arrays or Map (Collections -> Map ) ?

With arrays: just create one array with the dimensions you need. In your case:

```
Array[number_of_itens_to_store][3]
// 3 => 0 = id, 1 = x, 2 =y, 3 = speed
```

With Maps: take a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html . You can use your ID as the `K` (key) and an array as the value.

You can take a look at Collections (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) and even create your own collection, just following the tutorials.